# emacs (osx + iterm2) define-key input-decode-map deprecated?

Tags: emacs, iterm2

I have following define-key for iterm2 - emacs use.

```
 (define-key input-decode-map "\e[1;31" (kbd "C-;"))
 (define-key input-decode-map "\e[1;32" (kbd "C-="))
 (define-key input-decode-map "\e[1;33" (kbd "C-:"))
```

After I upgrade emacs 24.5.1 it stopped working.
What's the correct syntax for it?

**EDIT**

I used 24.3 before

c-h l gives

> b RET C-a C-n C-n C-n C-n C-x b i n p u t C-g C-x C-f DEL DEL DEL ~ /
>   . e m a c RET C-d ESC x m a g i t - s t a t u s RET g C-a C-n C-n C-n
>   C-n C-n C-n C-n C-n TAB TAB TAB TAB TAB TAB k y g C-a C-n C-n C-p C-p
>   C-p C-n C-p C-a C-n C-n C-x o C-c g s m a r t SPC p a r e n s C-g C-g
>   C-n C-n C-n C-x ESC p s m a r t SPC p a r e n RET C-a C-n C-x d RET g
>   C-a C-n C-n C-n C-p C-p C-s s m a r t - p a C-a C-s C-a C-n C-n C-a
>   C-x ESC p s m a r t C-n C-n C-n C-g RET g ^ R R O O T _ o r i g RET
>   ESC ! s h e l l RET C-g ESC ! e C-g ESC x s h e l l RET q RET q u i t
>   RET C-d ESC x e s h e l l RET l s RET c p SPC DEL DEL DEL l n SPC - s
>   SPC g C-a C-k c d SPC . . / b i n RET l l RET l s RET . / s u TAB DEL
>   h TAB RET f g RET p s SPC DEL DEL DEL DEL DEL n e t t DEL s t a t SPC
>   - a n o SPC | g r e p SPC 8 0 8 9 RET ESC O A DEL 0 RET C-h l C-g C-x 1 C-x b C-s C-s C-s RET C-h l

my emacs is

```
 #!/bin/sh
 which osascript > /dev/null 2>&1 && osascript -e 'tell application "Emacs" to activate'
 emacsclient -nw -c "$@"
```

Comment: Upgrade from which earlier version?  What does `C-h l` say?  How do you start Emacs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was due to the fact that the way I invoke emacs has changed.

I used to do `emacs -nw`

Now I start emacs-server and attach emacs-client.

And it breaks the `input-decode-map`

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gnu.emacs.help/ZGu2MNkJGrI

You need to do wrap them inside `defadvice` like the following.

```
(defadvice terminal-init-xterm (after map-S-up-escape-sequence 
activate) 
  (define-key input-decode-map "\e[1;2A" [S-up]) 

)
```